# Use of Pagination and MySQL queries

Tags: php, html

We have using the pagination 123 buttons, here if we click next button also means it should go to the next page. But here it doesnt go to the next page because here im passing the _POST variable in sql query to the where conditions so if click the next page it doesnt show the relevant page.
we think the POST variable value doesn't updated after when we click other pages. here is my Code. Thanks in advance.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  $bool = true;     
  $gender=$_POST['gender'];      
 } 

 if(($bool == true) 
 {

   $bool1=true;
   $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Sakthi");      
  if (!$connection)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("nursingcarein",$connection);

  if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
  $start_from = ($page-1) * 3;

  $gender1=$gender;
  $profession1=$profession;
  $state1=$state;

  /**** Here gender value doesnt update when click the next page i think we have a error in this query ****/      
  $sql = "SELECT id,description,name FROM nursereg WHERE gender='$gender1' LIMIT     $start_from, 3";

  $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$connection);
  echo "<table>
  <tr><td>Image</td><td>Description</td></tr>";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs_result)) {
    echo" <tr>";
        echo"<td>"; echo "<img src='image1.php?id=".$row['id']."'>"; echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>"; echo  $row['name']; echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>"; echo  $row['description']; echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
     };
  echo"</table>"; 
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM nursereg";
 $rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
  $total_records = $row[0];
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 5);    
 for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
   $pageno = $i;
       echo "<a href='index2.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";   
     };
 };

 ?>
```

Comment: If you are afraid that $_POST does not change its value, you can always use `var_dump` or `echo` functions to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pagination uses a href, this does not invoke a POST as your code suggests

```
$gender1=$_POST['gender'];
```

Try to add the gender to the pagination and fetch via GET

```
echo "<a href=\"index2.php?page=$i&gender=$gender1\">".$i."</a> ";
```

And then in your code

```
$gender1 = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : $_GET['gender'];
```

Comment: You probably want to escape the quotes around the link